# Trouble With Displaying Data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio

I am trying to display my mysql database table on a DataGridView using c# . but nothings happening . please tell me where i've gone wrong in my code

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
           MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Database=project; user=root;password=''");
           conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM billing";

         MySqlDataAdapter bills = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
         MySqlCommandBuilder cbuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(bills);
         DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        bills.Fill(dtable);
         //the DataGridView
         DataGridView dgView = new DataGridView();

         //BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
         BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

         //set the BindingSource DataSource
         bSource.DataSource = dtable;

         //set the DataGridView DataSource
         dgView.DataSource = bSource;
         bills.Update(dtable);
 }
```

Comment: Is your connection string correct? I looked up the MySql connection string and it looks like it uses "Uid" instead of "user". Give that a try. https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please provide them.

Comment: no there arent any errors . hence i dont even know where im going wrong . nothing happens when i click button1 .

Comment: Can you not eliminate BindingSource and just set dgView.DataSource = dtable? @NavomiShetty

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? If you haven't, add a try-catch block around your button1_Click method and step through the code. Let us know if any errors come up then.

Comment: If it's at all possible, please also provide us with a copy of the db.